# Writing a csv file that is too large R

Tags: r, csv, large-files

I currently saved some data as a csv file on my computer. It has 581 rows, but when I try to open the saved file on my mac, the dataframe has been altered and the numbers app from which I am looking at my csv from says some data was deleted. Is there a way to fix this? Or is there a different type of file I can save my data as that would adjust for the number of rows?

This is how I am writing the csv. I'm trying to manually add my file to a github repo after it has been saved to my computer.

```
write.csv(coords, 'Top_50_Distances.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Try `write_csv()` from `readr`

Comment: How does the app say some rows were deleted? The question is not completely clear, can you please give more information?